# makefile commands commence before first target

Tags: c++, linux, variables, makefile

In make file I took the followng error message;
Makefile:4: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

Makefile:

```
LINK_TARGET = sample4
OBJS = \
    main.o \ 
    remainder.o \ 
    helloWorld.o 
REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)
clean :
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)
    echo Clean done
all: $(LINK_TARGET) 
    echo All done
$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    g++ -g -o $@ $^
%.o : %.cpp
    g++ -g -o $@ -c $<
%.dep : %.cpp
    g++ -M $(FLAGS) $< > $@
include $(OBJS: .o=.dep)
```

How would I fix this error? 
Thanks...

Comment: I'm guessing that the characters before `main.o` etc. are tabs rather than spaces. Also looks like you have some whitespace after your escape backslashes.

Comment: I fixed tabs problems but now I take  error message; main.o:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored
main.o:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Probably spaces after your backslashes.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thanks a lot. Remove spaces after backslashes and change last part of the makefile as; main.o : main.cpp helloWorld.cpp remainder.cpp
helloWorld.o : helloWorld.cpp remainder.cpp
remainder.o : remainder.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Tabs have a special meaning in makefiles, in that they mark command lines. You should ensure that you don't use tabs for indentation in makefiles.

Line continuation escapes should be the very last character in the line, including whitespace. Otherwise it is parsed as trying to escape a space rather than the new line.

Comment: Syntax-aware editing (e.g. `makefile-mode` in Emacs) can help detect both these problems (and you can obviously contribute patches or bug reports if not).  I presume alternatives exist for other editors.